# Jquery Chosen showing focus

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-chosen

I'm using Jquery chosen. but When I use Internet Explorer, after select a item, the focus keep there...
Look at Image.

What's happend ?

Can help me ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQuZJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

### Quick Answer (TL;DR)

- Jquery chosen has known incompatibility issues

#### Context

- jQuery chosen
- MSIE version compatibility

#### See also

- [Chosen jQuery widget doesn't work in Compatibility View of IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507435/chosen-jquery-widget-doesnt-work-in-compatibility-view-of-ie8)